Trouble moving directory with paramiko
I am trying to creating an automated process that retrieves a file/files from an API, downloads the files onto a local path, then moves the files to a remote path onto an SFTP.
API ---> Local Path---> SFTP
I'm successful with the first two parts of the process but I'm having trouble moving the specific set of files, or just the entire directory, from the local path to the SFTP using paramiko.
import paramiko
import os

####After successful connection to SFTP####

remotepath = "/incoming/encoura"
localpath = (r"C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1")

sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

The code above demonstrates me copying the entire directory, but terminal returns with PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. I received the same even after setting the folder permisisons to read and write.
import paramiko
import os

####After successful connection to SFTP####

remotepath = "/incoming/encoura"

localpath = (r"C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1")

os.chmod(r"C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1", 0o644)

sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

I've also explored using fnmatch to use a wildcard to search the local directory of files with an ".csv" extension.
import paramiko
import os

####After successful connection to SFTP####


remotepath = "/incoming/encoura"
localpath = (r"C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1\'*.txt'")
lst = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1")

for file in lst:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'*.txt'):
        sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)


Doing this, returns OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "C:\Users\sdgibbs\Documents\Folder1\'*.txt'" Upon my research, it looks like paramiko does not accept wildcard characters.
Having said all of that, are there any other modules or commands that support either moving a directory, or moving a specific file by name or extension to an SFTP? If not, is paramiko capable of saving the local file as something different onto the remote path?

@MartinPrikryl Thank you for the suggestion. I am going to try the zip/unzip method and will report back.

I wasn't suggesting zip/unzip method. That seems like lousy solution to me.
